# Storing multiple vectors

Tags: java, vector, data-structures

I have around 1,700 vectors in the form of:

```
a*x + b*y + c*z
```

I need to store it inside a memory structure in Java. So far, my idea was either store the data:

- Inside 2-dimensional arrays
- Inside lists that hold arrays of 3 values

What would be the optimal move here ?

Comment: Do what you believe is the simplest implementation. A few KB of memory won't make much difference, your time is *so much* more valuable.

Comment: @PeterLAwrey Said the Java developer to the embedded systems engineer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `a*x + b*y + c*z`. To me that's just a scalar quantity (or possibly a matrix). Could you possibly elaborate?

Comment: Didnt find a way to mark x,y,z as unit vectors and a,b,c as scalars appended to each unit vector, I thought it was obvious :-/

Comment: Oh I see. If I were you, I'd use a class from a good linear algebra library.

Comment: @GillBates even embedded devices can have hundred of thousands of KB these days. Though if you have IoT perhaps you shouldn't be doing heavy lifting computation on your devices but use cloud servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice would be the one that you can prove the best. This means that when dealing with such questions you should profile different solutions and see which one is better with respect to your pattern of utilization of data.

I see multiple different choices:

- have a class `Coefficient { double a, b, c; }`
- use a `List<double[]>`
- use a `double[][]`

Probably the worst choice would be to wrap them into `Double` objects since it would place a lot of overhead everywhere.

My guess is that `double[][]` should be slightly the more efficient because JVM has native instructions to manage `array` but you won't get the same performance benefit you'd get from other languages because a bidimensional array in Java is still an array of arrays, so it's not contiguous in memory.

Probably `List<double[]>` and `double[][]` behave in a quite similar way with respect to reading or updating the values but things may change if you have a lot of insertions or deletions (assuming you resize the list to correct size before adding elements).

In the end just profile the code and check the results.

Comment: Instead of creating a new class called `Coefficient`, a `Vector3D.Double` class should be created or utilized from a third-party vector math library. This will also enrich the application down the road.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: any class which provides the same functionality would suffice. It was just to point out that a class which wraps all of them is a third solution not considered by OP.

Comment: I think Apache Commons Math lib should help out, what do you think ?